# Why was my edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I've fixed a misspelling of OSX El Capitan in an older post, why was it rejected?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I've posted the question and the answer below to share my thoughts and get community feedback on the action taken.

---

While there is nothing wrong as such with the edit (it did fix a minor issue in the post) it's worthwhile to keep the following in mind:

- There are significantly bigger issues with this post than the misspelling of the name of OSX 10.11. As written the question and the problem it describes are rather hard to understand. So if you already have the editor open, why not go the full way and also improve the readability of the post as such?
- Any edit on a post will bounce the question back onto the front page. So if you edit an old post please make sure it's not only worth the edit in itself but also that fact that it pushes a more recent question off the front page.
- Any edit done by users below 2000 points of reputation is placed into the review queue for suggested edits and reviewed by several high-rep users. As above, while I'm sure we have enough high-rep users to avoid a huge burden regarding the suggested edit reviews, make their time spent on the review of an edit a time well-spent

So in this case I choose to reject the edit as "doing harm", even though the harm was primarily to the review system and the users doing the review, and not so much on the post itself.

Comment: In principle, agreeable.  But the "all the way" could do with examples? What else was there to be fixed (as you see it and think worthwhile)? [That is: I see a few human language issues that are fixable, now. But ultimately I'd have to resort to a clarification comment, as I think it is just a bit too 'hard' to make out what's really asked here. Ultimately, I think if you are confident to know all what needs fixing, an edit by nohillside would give the most insight. Maybe with comments here]

Comment: @LangLangC Thanks for the feedback, you are absolutely right about "show it, don't just talk about it". My main critique regarding the question is along the same lines as yours: It's hard to understand and contains a lot of irrelevant stuff. If I would have stumbled across it shortly after it was posted I might have either commented accordingly or even put it on hold.

Comment: Having said that: Paragraphs 1 and 2 contain the actual question, paragraph 3 and 4 aren't really necessary at all. I understand that not all users editing questions would dare to actually remove half of the question, but in this situation it might be necessary.